# Line between userControls update only when lose focus in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, drawing, lines

About my program:
In my MainWindow I have a Ribbon bar with all kinds of buttons. Below that I have a clean Canvas. One of the buttons adds a UserControl to the Canvas (entity), and if there is more than one entity, a different button can add a UserControl (relationship) that connects 2 entities by a simple line.

Until now everything works great. The problem is when I move one of the UserControls around the Canvas, the line is not moving with it. Only when the mouse courser moves to one of the Ribbon buttons does the line update to its correct location.
How do I fix this?

The code for the Connector:

```
public partial class Connector : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(Point), typeof(Connector),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Point)));

    public Point Source
    {
        get { return (Point)this.GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DestinationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Destination", typeof(Point), typeof(Connector),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Point)));

    public Point Destination
    {
        get { return (Point)this.GetValue(DestinationProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(DestinationProperty, value); }
    }

    public Connector()
    {
        LineSegment segment = new LineSegment(default(Point), true);
        PathFigure figure = new PathFigure(default(Point), new[] { segment }, false);
        PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry(new[] { figure });
        BindingBase sourceBinding =
           new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(SourceProperty) };
        BindingBase destinationBinding =
           new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(DestinationProperty) };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
            figure, PathFigure.StartPointProperty, sourceBinding);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
            segment, LineSegment.PointProperty, destinationBinding);
        Content = new Path
        {
            Data = geometry,
            StrokeThickness = 3,
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            MinWidth = 1,
            MinHeight = 1
        };
    }
```

The code for adding a connection:

```
 private void Add_Relationship_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

        Controls.RelationshipControl relcon = new Controls.RelationshipControl(((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).entityDsg);
        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).entityDsg.Children.Add(relcon);
        Entity fromEntity = (Entity)cb_from.SelectedItem;
        Entity toEntity = (Entity)cb_to.SelectedItem;
        EntityControl dest1 = null;
        EntityControl dest2 = null;

        foreach (UIElement child in ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).entityDsg.Children)
        {
            if (child is EntityControl)
            {
                EntityControl ec = (EntityControl)child;
                if (ec.tb_name.Text.Equals(fromEntity.entityName.ToString()))
                    dest1 = (EntityControl)child;
                if (ec.tb_name.Text.Equals(toEntity.entityName.ToString()))
                    dest2 = (EntityControl)child;
            }

        }

        Connector conn1 = new Connector();
        conn1.SetBinding(Connector.SourceProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source = relcon,
            Path = new PropertyPath(RelationshipControl.AnchorPointProperty)
        });
        conn1.SetBinding(Connector.DestinationProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source = dest1,
            Path = new PropertyPath(EntityControl.AnchorPointProperty)
        });

        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).entityDsg.Children.Add(conn1);

        Connector conn2 = new Connector();
        conn2.SetBinding(Connector.SourceProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source = relcon,
            Path = new PropertyPath(RelationshipControl.AnchorPointProperty)
        });
        conn2.SetBinding(Connector.DestinationProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source = dest2,
            Path = new PropertyPath(EntityControl.AnchorPointProperty)
        });

        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).entityDsg.Children.Add(conn2);
    }
```

Thanks is advance.